# How update relational table with code first migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations

my technical question is really short: How update a relational table created when using Code First Migration?

Here the table **StockKeepingUnitFeature** is created automaticaly but I do not have any object class to update that table. How can we do?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<StockKeepingUnit>()
            .HasMany(b => b.Feature)
            .WithMany(a => a.StockKeepingUnit)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("StockKeepingUnitId")
                          .MapRightKey("FeatureId")
                          .ToTable("StockKeepingUnitFeature"));
        }
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here the solution**: I found that link from Microsoft, very helpful! [Relationships, Navigation Properties, and Foreign Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

Thereafter here my code to update the relational table:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return query;
    }
/// <summary>
    /// Update the relational StockKeepingUnitFeature table
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stockKeepingUnitSlug"></param>
    /// <param name="featureSlug"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool AddFeatureToStockKeepingUnit(string stockKeepingUnitSlug, string featureSlug)
    {
        StockKeepingUnit sku = this.AllIncluding(stockKeepingUnit => stockKeepingUnit.Feature).Where(s => s.Slug == stockKeepingUnitSlug).FirstOrDefault();
        Feature feature = context.Features.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Slug == featureSlug);

        if (feature != null && sku != null)
        {
            sku.Feature.Add(feature);
            context.StockKeepingUnits.Attach(sku);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Update the relational StockKeepingUnitFeature database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stockKeepingUnitSlug"></param>
    /// <param name="featureSlug"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool RemoveFeatureFromStockKeepingUnit(string stockKeepingUnitSlug, string featureSlug)
    {
        StockKeepingUnit sku = this.AllIncluding(stockKeepingUnit => stockKeepingUnit.Feature).Where(s => s.Slug == stockKeepingUnitSlug).FirstOrDefault();
        Feature feature = context.Features.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Slug == featureSlug);

        if (feature != null && sku != null)
        {
            context.Entry(feature).Collection(s => s.StockKeepingUnit).CurrentValue = null;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Hoping that it will be useful to the community,

Cheers